# ng 1.0.0-beta.21 does not create shared directory

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm new to using Angular-cli ... I'm using version  1.0.0-beta.21

It does not create a shared directory.  Has this been changed from previous version of the cli?

Comment: Are you using node and express?

Comment: Have you tried installing a previous version to find out? Were you expecting it to create that directory?

Answer (score 1):

This was removed a while ago... https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/b250cb69aa1eb72f6a3131b48f280fb375ed1d79

`shared` was part of the barrel strategy that is less necessary with introduction of `NgModule`